# Webots simulation, damped world

Tags: webots

I am a master's student at the physics department of the Goethe University Frankfurt am Main. I started to learn about Webots, which I intend to use for my master's thesis. I am at the very beginning, so I am still figuring out how different details of the program work.

I encountered an issue, which source I cannot find. In the simplest simulations, like a ball bouncing off the ground, or a pendulum, there seems to be energy loss. All the parameters responsible for damping and friction (in "contact properties" and "damping" node) are zero. The elasticity ("bounce" node) is set to 1, so 100% elasticity. Nevertheless, the systems lose energy. Can it be that this happens purely because the time is discrete? For example, when the ball hits the wall, its velocity after the bounce is equal to the one a time step before the bounce? So it wouldn't be the exact velocity that a real ball would have in the moment it reaches the wall, but a short moment before? Do my questions make any sense to You? I am new to the world of simulations in general, so I don't know if this is a common issue.

Comment: are you talking about the loss of potential energy in a simulation? ... this site is not a forum ... it is a question and answer site ... please ask one clear, focused question

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange @dražen-hukić! Please check the guidelines to [ask a good question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That will make it easier for others to understand your need and to answer you.

Comment: I will reformulate the question with a concrete example. My world consists only of a rectangular floor and a solid with a shape of a ball. There is no friction between the ball and the floor, there is also no damping added to the system. The “bounce” value is set to 1, which means that the ball hits the floor completely elastically. When I start the simulation, I expect the ball to bounce endlessly, without any energy loss. But, that does not happen, the ball losses some energy every time it hits the floor, that is, it jumps lower. My question is, where is the energy loss?

Comment: @DraženHukić this info does not belong in a comment ... please edit your question instead

Comment: maybe the floor has some elasticity